# React Native [remoteConfig/throttled] fetch() operation cannot be completed successfully, due to throttling

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

I am calling this inside `useEffect` in my `App.js` file, and it gives the error "fetch() operation cannot be completed ,due to throttling" What could be the issue ?

```
export const initRemoteConfig = async () => {
  try {
    await remoteConfig.setDefaults({
      min_app_version: '4.5.0',
    });

    await remoteConfig.fetch();
    const activated = remoteConfig.activate();

    if (activated) {
      let confVal = remoteConfig.getValue('min_app_version');
      let result = confVal;
    } else {
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('FR Remote config error: ', err.message);
  }
};
```